# 2d array Bubble sort fix pls

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

---

so if you input 3x3 array it should be like this
987
654
321

and i want to bubble sort it to
123
456
789

but i have problem on end line
can anyone help me

When I execute my code, the output looks like this:

```
Please enter number of rows:2
Please enter number of columns: 2
Please enter 4 numbers to sort: 8 4 6 2
Sorted numbers:
[[I@776ec8df [[I@776ec8df [[I@776ec8df [[I@776ec8df
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class 2dsort 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Please enter number of rows: ");
        var row = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Please enter number of columns: ");
        var col = sc.nextInt();
        
        int[][] matrix = new int[row][col];
        
        System.out.print("Please enter " + (row*col) + " numbers to sort: ");
        
        for(int x = 0; x < row; x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < col; y++)
            {
                matrix[x][y] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        
        for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++)
                for(int t = 0; t < matrix[x].length - y - 1; y++)
                    if(matrix[x][t] > matrix[x][t+1])
                    {
                        int temp = matrix[x][t];
                        matrix[x][t] = matrix[x][t+1];
                        matrix[x][t + 1] = temp;
                    }
    
        //I think this is my problem but idk how to fix
        System.out.println("Sorted numbers:");
        for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++)
            System.out.print(matrix + " ");
        System.out.println();
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue appears to be here:

`System.out.print(matrix + " ");`

You're not printing out the values held by the matrix.

You likely want to retrieve the values at the specific indices using `matrix[x][y]`

I ran your code using `System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");` and while the code execution worked and printed the matrix values appropriately, your sorting algorithm isn't giving you the results you want. I'll leave that for you to fix, but your printing issue is solved.